# Error listing directory: Invalid Argument to date encode [3082-80-91]

Tags: batch-file, encode, winscp, invalid-argument

Currently working with WinSCP through the command line. Simple process that when run, copies remote files to local directory. I get a good way through the first-time download of files when I encounter this error:

> Error listing directory '/FE_HDD_SyncFolder/Diags Old PC and Tape/DIAGS NON DG/QAPLUS 5.5 pc diags'.
>   Unexpected directory listing line 'EMM386.EXE////120926/0/0/3082/80/91/40/24/1/1/1'.
>   Invalid argument to date encode [3082-80-91]
>   (A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip: Abort

I am unsure what it means and I can't find any other questions here that give a straight answer to what this error means. Is the [3082-80-91] the error code or the date that the code is reaching and reading it as invalid?

Let me know if you need anything else to answer the question.
Thanks again!

EDIT: Tried doing it though the client. I get the same error. With the client I can skip the file causing the error. I did that and the rest seems to be downloading just fin. Maybe it's just that specific file that is causing the error? Still don't know what the error is so if someone could lend a hand still, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Log file would help with debugging this. So far it looks like your server produces directory listing that WinSCP does not understand.

Comment: Still transferring the rest of the files. I hit "SKIP" on the file the produced the error and it is continuing with the download. When you say a directory listing it doesn't understand, do you mean that a file type is incorrect or maybe a folder is corrupt or something?

Comment: No. I've mean what I wrote. That the directory listing format produced by the server is not understood by WinSCP. I cannot tell mode without a log file.

Comment: Ok I can not, for the life of me, find how to get logs from WinSCP.

Comment: Google for "winscp command line logging"? See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging